# Parcel PostCSS preprocessing /dynamic imports not working

Tags: css, postcss, parceljs

I'm trying to convert from `Sass` to `PostCSS` with `PreCSS` plugin on `Parcel`, but `Parcel` keeps importing an unchanged `CSS` file. There is a correctly processed file in the `dist` folder, but `Parcel` imports another file in the `Dist` folder that was never processed. 
source file structure:

```
index.html
Terminal.html
StyleSheets
-->index.pcss
-->Terminal.pcss
Scripts
-->index.js
-->Terminal.js
```

And here is my `parcel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('cssnano'),
    require('precss')
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that, instead of putting the plugins in `parcel.config.js` you should put them in `.postcssrc` like this:

```
{
  "modules": false,
  "plugins": {
    "autoprefixer": {
      "grid": true
    },
    "cssnano": {

    },
    "precss": {

    }
  }
}
```